# Dapper.Contrib Generate Update Script With ROWLOCK

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-extensions

I am using Dapper as ORM and generating insert,update script by Dapper.Contrib extensions. I want to generate Update script include Rowlock. 
Is there any usage except changing generic code below in SqlMapperExtensions.

```
 public static bool Update<T>(this IDbConnection connection....
     var proxy = entityToUpdate as IProxy;
     ......
     ......
     var sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.AppendFormat("update {0} set ",name);

     var allProperties = TypePropertiesCache(type);
     .......
```

Answer (score 0):

Dapper.Contrib and the extensions there does not support `ROWLOCK` and there is no way to configure Dapper to use it, so right now you would have to modify the base code or add your own extension with support for `ROWLOCK`.